# How do you prevent install of "devDependencies" NPM modules for Node.js (package.json)?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have this in my package.json file (shortened version):

```
{
  "name": "a-module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "coffee-script":      ">= 1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "stylus":             ">= 0.17.0"
  }
}
```

I am using NPM version 1.1.1 on Mac 10.6.8.

When I run the following command from the project root, it installs both the `dependencies` *and* `devDependencies`:

```
npm install
```

I was under the impression that this command installed the `devDependencies`:

```
npm install --dev
```

How do I make it so `npm install` only installs `dependencies` (so production environment only gets those modules), while something like `npm install --dev` installs both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`?

Comment: According to the doc, you are right, the --dev installs the devdeps, otherwise, only the deps. http://npmjs.org/doc/json.html. I know this works for named packages, at least.

Comment: if you come across this Question in 2015, --save-dev switch does the trick exactly as asked in this Question.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/3718119 gives a nice explanation to differences between `dependencies` and `devDependencies` and when each of them is used.

Answer (score 1319, accepted):

The `npm install` command will install the `devDependencies` along other `dependencies` when run inside a package directory, in a development environment (the default).

In version 8.x and above use [`--omit=dev`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install#omit) flag to install only regular dependencies:

```
npm install --omit=dev
```

This will install **only** `dependencies`, and not `devDependencies`, regardless of the value of the `NODE_ENV` environment variable.

If you use 6.x or an earlier version, you need to use the `--only=prod` flag instead.

**Note:**
Before v3.3.0 of npm (2015-08-13), the option was called `--production`, i.e.

```
npm install --production
```

You may also need `--no-optional` flag.

Comment: So if we publish one module. Do we need to remove the devDependencies from package.json?

Comment: Agate's reasoning is probably to remove devDependencies so that consumers installing your package with `npm install yourpackage.tgz` don't also get the devDependencies.  However, that is already the case.  See Kevin Cox's answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15826602/825588).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html

"By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies. With the --production flag, npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies."

Comment: Oh my god. I totally had `NODE_ENV=production` from something else I was doing and could not figure out for the life of me why `npm install` wouldn't install dependencies. Thanks for the thorough answer.

Comment: `npm install --dev`  would only install dev dependencies

Comment: For npm 3.3 and onward: npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--only=dev` instead.

Comment: The problem with this "solution" is that it treats any non-"production" environment as "development". It shouldn't. What if I have a "staging" environment where I only want production deps?

Comment: As of npm 6.9.0, https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install clearly documents BOTH `--production` and `--only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]}`.

Comment: According to the current [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) it is still only `--production`: "With the `--production` flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies."

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira: did you also notice the "The `--only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]}` argument will cause either only `devDependencies` or only `non-devDependencies` to be installed regardless of the NODE_ENV." part?

Comment: --production flag is still there.

Comment: it still installs 57 packages... even thou the `packages.json` does not contain them, they are there in the `node_modules` folder

Answer (score 316):

I run into that problem too! npm install is somewhat confusing and web posts keep bringing in the -d/--dev flags as if there is an explicit 'development' install mode.

- **`npm install`** will install both "*dependencies*" and "*devDependencies*"
- **`npm install --production`** will only install "*dependencies*"
- **`npm install --dev`** will only install "*devDependencies*"

Comment: WARNING: If `NODE_ENV` is set to `production` and you run `npm install` it will not install dev dependencies. I ran into this issue in my Dockerfile.

Comment: @vaughan I've run into this too, can be solved by running `npm --production=false install` (though not sure if this will work alongside the --dev flag)

Comment: @vaughan what if `echo $NODE_ENV` returns empty?

Comment: why would someone use `npm install --dev`? in mean in what scenario? e.g. they already installed by `npm install --production` and now decide to do some test?

Comment: @JimRaynor I have a project where the production dependencies are installed globally and the development dependencies are installed locally. It's a test harness, so not a usual use case at all (and not how I'd design it), but it's definitely a use case. We run --production with a -g flag, and a --dev without the -g.

Answer (score 164):

The new option is:

```
npm install --only=prod
```

If you want to install only devDependencies:

```
npm install --only=dev
```

Comment: This answers the opposite of the question. OP is asking how NOT to install devDependencies.

Comment: you are partially correct @musicin3d, that's why on the first part I answered how to install prod only dependencies and on the second part how to install dev only dependencies, just in case.

Comment: Hey there. I left that comment before @user1614572 added the part about `--only=prod`. You, sir, are partially correct. ;P

Comment: can we include separate dependency for the deployment?

Comment: @Jacques: why is this the correct answer as of 2015//2016? As opposed to...? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install clearly documents BOTH `--production` and `--only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]}`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu you’re asking me a question about a comment from 3 years ago while linking to *todays* documentation?

Comment: @Jacques: here: http://web.archive.org/web/20160115001135/https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install. Better?

Comment: @DanDascalescu You missed the point. It was posted in 2016, I had no way at the time to know if things would change in the future. Why are you commenting on stuff from years ago that brings nothing new or valuable to the answers/comments?

Comment: @Jacques: I didn't miss the point, but let me clarify: [at the time you commented, the documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20160115001135/https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) showed both options, with no indication as to which would be preferred or new. What made you claim "This is the correct answer"? Furthermore, both options are still equally valid today, and if you care about integrity, you'd delete your 2016 comment, and/or add a new one if you do have reasons to say that `--production` is deprecated. SO isn't a set-in-time blog post. It's an evolving wiki. Let's keep it current!

Comment: It’s a comment, not an answer. I don’t go checking all my comments periodically. I’ve never seen people go update *comments* from years ago. You basically came on here to criticize that I put a year on my comment. I won’t be responding further. Have fun trolling other people.

Answer (score 56):

If you have already installed all your dependencies, and you want to avoid having to download your production packages from NPM again, you can simply type:

```
npm prune --production
```

This will remove your dev dependencies from your `node_modules` folder, which is helpful if you're trying to automate a two step process like

1. Webpack my project, using dev dependencies
2. Build a Docker image using only production modules

Running `npm prune` in between will save you from having to reinstall everything!

Comment: In 2021, npm v7.11 you just need `npm install --only=production` even if you installed the whole thing and it achieves the same result

Comment: In 2023 npm warns when using --only=production with the following:
npm WARN config only Use `--omit=dev` to omit dev dependencies from the install.

Answer (score 47):

If you read this POST in 2016, please achieve what you want by using

```
--only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]}
```

argument will cause either only devDependencies or only non-devDependencies to be installed regardless of the NODE_ENV.

from: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: Why capitalize "POST"? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install clearly documents BOTH `--production` and `--only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]}`.

Answer (score 23):

When using "npm install" the modules are loaded and available throughout your application regardless of if they are "devDependencies" or "dependencies". Sum of this idea: everything which your package.json defines as a dependency (any type) gets installed to node_modules.

The purpose for the difference between dependencies/devDependencies/optionalDependencies is what consumers of your code can do w/ npm to install these resources.

Per the documentation: https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html...

> If someone is planning on downloading and using your module in their
>   program, then they probably don't want or need to download and build
>   the external test or documentation framework that you use.
>
> In this case, it's best to list these additional items in a
>   devDependencies hash.
>
> These things will be installed whenever the --dev configuration flag
>   is set. This flag is set automatically when doing npm link or when
>   doing npm install from the root of a package, and can be managed like
>   any other npm configuration param. See config(1) for more on the
>   topic.

However, to resolve this question, if you want to ONLY install the "dependencies" using npm, the following command is:

```
npm install --production
```

This can be confirmed by looking at the Git commit which added this filter (along with some other filters [listed below] to provide this functionality).

Alternative filters which can be used by npm:

```
--save          => updates dependencies entries in the {{{json}}} file
--force         => force fetching remote entries if they exist on disk 
--force-latest  => force latest version on conflict
--production    => do NOT install project devDependencies
--no-color      => do not print colors
```

@dmarr try using npm install --production

Answer (score 20):

I suggest to use `npm ci`. If you want to install only production-needed packages (as you wrote - without `devDependencies`) then:

```sh
npm ci --only=production
```

or

```sh
NODE_ENV=production npm ci
```

If you prefer oldschool `npm install` then:

```sh
npm install --production
```

or

```sh
NODE_ENV=production npm install
```

[Here is good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48524475) why you should use `npm ci`.

Comment: Cool, it does work with `npm ci` as well, not just `npm install`!

Comment: This is good advice. However now `--only=production` should be `--omit=dev`.

Answer (score 18):

npm will install dev dependencies when installing from inside a package (if there is a `package.json` in the current directory).  If it is from another location (npm registry, git repo, different location on the filesystem) it only installs the dependencies.

Comment: Could you please reformulate? I think you made a mistake in your parenthesis, I think you forgot to close it earlier and your frase doesn't make much sense to me (non-native english speaker). Johann's comment under Rohan Singh answer pointed me to look to your answer (because my doubt was exactly the same that agate's doubt), and no success. I still don't get it how `npm install some-module` will not install dev dependencies of `some-module`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed.  I don't understand the rest of your question however.

Answer (score 7):

It's worth mentioning that you can use the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to achieve the same result. Particularly useful if you're containerizing your Node application (e.g. Docker).

```sh
NODE_ENV=production npm install
```

The above code will install all your dependencies but the dev ones (i.e. `devDependencies`).

if you need to use environment variables in your `Dockerfile` more information can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement).

Environment variables are easy to overwrite whenever needed (e.g. if you want to run your test suite say on Travis CI). If that were the case you could do something like this:

```sh
docker run -v $(pwd):/usr/src/app --rm -it -e NODE_ENV=production node:8 npm install
```

[NPM Documentation here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#production)

> production
>
> - Default: false
> - Type: Boolean
>     Set to true to run in "production" mode.
>
>   1. devDependencies are not installed at the topmost level when running local npm install without any arguments.
>   2. Set the NODE_ENV="production" for lifecycle scripts.

Happy containerization **=)**

Answer (score 6):

`npm install --production --no-optional`

It installs only deps from `dependencies` and will ignore `optionalDependencies` and `devDependencies`

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a problem in the docker node:current-slim (running npm 7.0.9) where `npm install` appeared to ignore `--production`, `--only=prod` and `--only=production`. I found two work-arounds:

1. use ci instead (`RUN npm ci --only=production`) which requires an up-to-date package-lock.json
2. before `npm install`, brutally edit the package.json with:

`RUN node -e 'const fs = require("fs"); const pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./package.json", "utf-8")); delete pkg.devDependencies; fs.writeFileSync("./package.json", JSON.stringify(pkg), "utf-8");'`

This won't edit your working package.json, just the one copied to the docker container.
Of course, this shouldn't be necessary, but if it is (as it was for me), there's your hack.

Answer (score 4):

Need to add to chosen answer: As of now, `npm install` in a package directory (containing `package.json`) will install devDependencies, whereas `npm install -g` will not install them.

Comment: Yes, `-g` will not install `devDependencies`, but it does install the packages globally, which is often not the intended result.

Answer (score 4):

I have found that, when trying to install dev dependencies for a package that contains a node addon, you cannot avoid building the addon when running npm install --dev even if you just want to install the devDependencies. So, I had to go around npm's back:

```
node -e 'console.log( Object.keys( require( "./package.json" ).devDependencies ) );' | \
sed  -e "s/^[^']*'//" -e "s/'.*$//" | \
xargs npm install
```

Or, better (and more succinctly) yet,

```
node -e 'Object.keys( require( "./package.json" ).devDependencies )
.map( function( item ){ console.log( item ) } );' | xargs npm install
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `npm install packageName --save` this will add package in **dependencies**, if you use `npm install packageName --save-dev` then it **devDependencies**.

`npm install packageName --save-dev` should be used for adding packages for development purpose. Like adding TDD packages (Chai, mocha, etc). Which are used in development and not in production.

Comment: The OP is not having an issue saving dependencies in `package.json` but *once these dependencies are already saved*, then how to coerce `npm` to install only one specific type of dependency. When I read your answer here, I did not learn anything that helps solve the problem posed by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install --production` is the right way of installing node modules which are required for production. Check the documentation for more details