# nodejs npm install platform specific packages

Tags: node.js, npm

My nodejs app runs on Raspberry Pi and uses a SPI interface.
SPI is not available on windows.

The npm package I am using fails to install on windows as I would expect.
I would like to develop and do some testing on Windows but NPM failing 
to load this module forces too many manual workarounds.

What I would like the ability to install the SPI module when 
NPM install is ran on a Raspberry and install a stub module to fake a 
SPI on windows.

In pseudo code : file package.json

```
"dependencies-for-linux": { "pi-spi":  "~1.0.1"},
"dependencies-for-win": { "pi-spi": "./some_local_file_to_fake_pi_spi_api"}
```

An alternative approach could be to not abort the install is the package fails.
Pseudo code for the alternative: file package.jon

```
"dependencies-that-do-not-fail-install" : { "pi-spi":  "~1.0.1"}
```

my_module.js

```
 var pi_spi = null
    try{
        pi_spi = require("pi-spi")
    }
    catch (e) {
        pi_spi = require("fake-pi-spi")
```

Either solution would be great.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You could make a node script that you run at `postinstall` where you check the `platform` and programatically `npm install` (via `require('npm')`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OS module in Node.js to get the current os.arch() which will return either 'x64', 'arm', etc...

You can use this in my_module.js to see which package to require.

https://nodejs.org/api/os.html

Comment: How do i use os.arch to alter the npm installation of packages?  I see os.arch can in the js code require an alternative package.  But the package that fails to install will mess up the installation before I get this far.  So i think I need to be able to control what gets installed.

Comment: In that case you when you run npm install in windows you can specify the --only=dev flag.  Then you can change your "dependencies-for-win" to devDependencies for the fake-pi-spi.  See more info here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268259/how-do-you-prevent-install-of-devdependencies-npm-modules-for-node-js-package?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, the dots are now connected. optionalDependencies allows for the spi to fail when on windows, try catch on the require("pi-spi").