# Why does the npm package I created have a node_modules folder in it when installing it as dependency for another module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies, node-modules

I just published my first npm package. When I install the package as dependency in my project, I open the project folder in node_modules and see that it also has a node_modules folder with one package, `history` in the folder. I don't have any regular dependencies for my project, only devDependencies so I don't understand why this is happening? You can see my package.json file and try installing the module from the github page here https://github.com/danielyaa5/react-contextulize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `npm install` **will** install `devDependencies` under many circumstances.

Try explicitly installing in production mode:

```
npm install --only=production
```

Here is a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268259/how-do-you-prevent-install-of-devdependencies-npm-modules-for-node-js-package/9276112#9276112) with more info.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me though, there must be another way where I don't have to tell my users to install it like this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to tell your users anything. In production systems where `NODE_ENV=production` is set, the devDependencies will be skipped.

Answer (score -1):

When you install an npm package as a dependency for another module, npm installs the package along with its dependencies in the node_modules folder of the dependent module. This is a fundamental aspect of how npm manages dependencies.

Here's a breakdown of what happens:

Dependency Resolution:
When you specify a package as a dependency in your package.json file, npm determines the versions of that package and its dependencies that are compatible with your project. This information is stored in the node_modules folder.

Dependency Installation:
npm installs the specified package and its dependencies in the node_modules folder of your project. Each dependency gets its own folder within node_modules.

Scoped Dependencies:
If your package has its own dependencies, they are installed in a nested node_modules folder within your package's folder. This ensures that each package can have its own isolated set of dependencies without conflicting with the dependencies of other packages.

Flat vs. Nested Structure:
npm attempts to maintain a flat structure by default, meaning that it tries to install all dependencies in a single node_modules folder at the top level. However, in certain cases, a nested structure is unavoidable due to conflicting dependencies.

The node_modules folder within your package may contain the dependencies necessary for your package to function correctly.

Package Scripts:
Some npm packages may include scripts that are executed during the installation process. These scripts might perform additional setup or configuration.

In summary, the node_modules folder in your package, when installed as a dependency, contains the dependencies required for your package to function correctly within the context of the dependent module. It's a standard practice to encapsulate dependencies for each module to avoid conflicts and ensure a clear dependency tree.

Comment: Are you aware of [our policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?