# reduce size of node_modules for production

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, npm-shrinkwrap

I created node_modules for uploading addon to online site from localhost with help of ngrok and using **npm install** in CommandPrompt. But the created node_modules folder size was 78mb. In that case i must reduce the size by removing the unwanted folders, so I surfed the internet and got two suggestions, as it could be efficient to get size reduced, they are: using **--production mode** and the other is using **shrinkwrap**.

As first step I used the command  **npm install --production** and **npm install --only=production** as specified here: [How do you prevent install of "devDependencies" NPM modules for Node.js (package.json)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268259/how-do-you-prevent-install-of-devdependencies-npm-modules-for-node-js-package), but I din't see any change in folder size.

Then referred on how to use shrinkwrap to reduce size as given in this site and tried it: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap, but it did not success.

Additionally I referred here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/modclean, where using the command **modclean -n default:safe** I got 10-11mb reduced.

But, still I have a large number of unwanted folders in node_modules. I have specified few needed dependencies in package.json as follows,

```
"dependencies": {
    "atlassian-connect-express": "2.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.14.2",
    "compression": "^1.6.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.0",
    "errorhandler": "^1.4.2",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-hbs": "*",
    "jugglingdb-sqlite3": "0.0.5",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "static-expiry": ">=0.0.5"
}
```

The dependencies I have given in package.json is few, but I see a large sets of folders created in node_modules. How can I reduce the size of node_modules, is there any other process?

Comment: Note that running `npm install --production` won't remove your devDependancies from `node_modules`; you need to delete `node_modules` first to see a reduction in size.

Answer (score 2):

As of NPM v3, all of the dependencies in your app are, where possible, kept in the top level of your `node_modules` - this makes it easier for NPM to remove duplicates, and prevents some nasty 'path too long' errors on Windows.

The important thing to realize is that when I say 'all of the dependencies in your app', I don't just mean the ones in your `package.json` - all of *those* packages will have their own dependencies too (and their dependencies might have dependencies of their own, and so on). This is why `node_modules` always has so many folders inside.

As an example - [`express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) has  28 dependencies, so that'd be a minimum of 29 folders in your `node_modules` if that was the only thing you'd installed - and that's without factoring in sub-dependencies.

So, to answer your question - aside from the things you specified, you *can't* make your `node_modules` any smaller, because you are using all of those folders! Just not always in the most direct way.

Comment: What I don't understand is why does NPM include the non-minified javascript files in node_modules even when using the --production flag? Shouldn't there be a way to only deliver minified packages?

Comment: @nocarrier: All `--production` does is exclude the development dependencies, nothing more. NPM doesn't really make any decisions for you about minification - you'd only be able to get minified code off of NPM if the package author published it that way. If you want to know why not, you'd have to ask the NPM devs, as I'm not psychic :p