# Node.js cannot find module, despite module being installed

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

- I build my application locally into a `dist` folder; package.json is also copied over
- `npm install --production` is run in the dist folder
- `dist` folder is then zipped up
- Zip is uploaded to server, where it is unzipped
- Attempting to run the application on the server results in `Error: cannot find module <module_name>`

This error occurs for any module unless I manually run `npm install <module_name>` after the unzip

Everything works fine if I run it from my `dist` folder, so it's not an issue with the pre-zip part

Running `npm install --production` after the unzip doesn't resolve anything (just says that all modules are up-to-date)

Deleting `node_modules` on the server, then running `npm install --production` makes everything work fine

Unzipping the zip file locally then running the application works fine

What am I missing/doing wrong?

EDIT: package.json:

```
{
    "name": "app-name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
        "email-validator": "^1.1.1",
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "express-jwt": "^5.3.0",
        "express-jwt-permissions": "^1.0.0",
        "firebase-admin": "^5.5.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0",
        "mailgun-js": "^0.13.1",
        "mysql2": "^1.5.0",
        "password-hash-and-salt": "^0.1.4",
        "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
        "sequelize": "^4.22.6",
        "sequelize-typescript": "^0.5.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.0.39",
        "@types/express-jwt": "0.0.38",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^7.2.4",
        "@types/node": "^8.0.51",
        "@types/sequelize": "^4.0.79",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "del": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-babel": "^7.0.0",
        "gulp-ssh": "^0.6.0",
        "gulp-typescript": "^3.2.3",
        "gulp-zip": "^4.0.0",
        "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
        "typescript": "^2.6.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: When it says that cannot find the module, it also says the path where it was looking. Check that is looking for the correct `node_modules` path.

Comment: There's no path in the error:
```Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)...etc```

(only path is the location of the file that's trying to load express)

Comment: Hm, ok. Can you check if you have `express` inside the `node_modules` folder? Maybe you have a global installation and don't remember that you installed it that way.

Comment: Also checked that, and express is not installed globally (and neither are any of the other modules that I use)

Comment: Is kinda weird. Can you show your package.json? I see that express, in their GitHub, tell to install globally a native command. Maybe that's the problem. By the way, are you saying that the folder `node_modules` contains the folder `express` with all the needed express files?

Comment: I've added the package.json contents to the question

Comment: Kind weird, yeah. I can't help anymore. I upvoted. Let's see if someone else can find what happens.

Comment: What versions of node/npm are you running on the server vs dev? What do the permissions on node_modules look like when unzipped vs npm installed? Are there any other differences between the server/local (mac vs linux, etc)?

Comment: Identical versions of both Node and NPM. 

Same error occurs even when I recursively chmod the entire node_modules directory to 777. 

Local machine is MacOS, server is Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Use npm install --only=production instead. As per this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268259/how-do-you-prevent-install-of-devdependencies-npm-modules-for-node-js-package)

Hope this helps, I am newbie to Node js, just trying to help