# Should the package-lock.json file be added to .gitignore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm, gitignore

To lock the versions of dependencies that are installed over a project, the command `npm install` creates a file called `package-lock.json`. This was made since [Node.js v8.0.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v8.0.0/) and [npm v5.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm5), as several of you might know.

Despite of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) and [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) recommendations about committing this file, several concerns regarding when you should avoid to do it, are also an option. Typically we commit in our projects, nevertheless, it is a peculiar question.

While we should commit the `package-lock.json` file by default, we have a specific case we should not. For instance, if we want to test the latest version of our project dependencies, it can be an option to add `package-lock.json` into `.gitignore`.

So, the questions are as follows:

1. Should the `package-lock.json` file be added to `.gitignore`?
2. Is there any particular situation that we **MUST** or **MUST NOT** do it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52499617/457268

Answer (score 356, accepted):

No, the `package-lock.json` **SHOULD NOT** be added to `.gitignore`. Instead, I strongly advise:

1. **Add the `package-lock.json` you to your version control repository**
2. **Use `npm ci` instead of `npm install`** when building your application both locally and in your deployment pipeline.
   (The `ci` command is available since npm@5.7, if in doubt upgrade your npm via:
    `npm install -g npm`.)

---

One of the biggest downside of the `npm install` command is its unexpected behavior that it may mutate the `package-lock.json`, whereas `npm ci` only uses the version in the lockfile and produces an error if the `package-lock.json` and `package.json` are out of sync.

Also, `npm ci` *requires* the existence of a `package-lock.json` and would print an error if it wasn't there.
There is a strong use-case for being able to trust that the project's dependencies resolve repeatably in a reliable way across different machines.

Furthermore, `npm ci` nukes the entire `node_modules` folder before adding the dependencies making sure you work with your actual dependencies instead of local changes while still being faster than a normal `npm install`.

From a `package-lock.json` you get exactly that: a known-to-work state with always exactly the same dependency tree.

In the past, I had projects without `package-lock.json` / `npm-shrinkwrap.json` / `yarn.lock` files whose build would fail one day because a random dependency got a breaking update. (While a lot of libraries respect the semvar versioning guideline, you have no guarantee they won't break on a minor upgrade.)

Those issue are hard to resolve as you sometimes have to guess what the last working version was.

In regards to testing the latest dependencies for your project: This is what `npm update` is for and I argue that it should be run by a developer, who also runs the test locally, who resolves issue if they may arise, and who then commits the changed `package-lock.json`. (If an upgrade fails, they can revert to the last working `package-lock.json`.)

Furthermore, I rarely upgrade all the dependencies at once (as that too might require further maintenance) but I rather cherry-pick the update I need (e.g. `npm update {dependency}`, or `npm install {dependency}@2.1.3`). Which is another reason why I would see it as a manual maintenance step.

If you really want to have it automated you could create a job for:

- checkout repository
- run npm update
- run tests

  - if tests passes, then commit and push to repository
  - else fail and report issue to be manually resolved

This is something I would see hosted on a CI server, e.g. Jenkins, and it should not be achieved through aforementioned reason through adding the file to the `.gitignore`.

---

Or to [quote npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks):

> It is highly recommended you commit the generated package lock to
> source control: this will allow anyone else on your team, your
> deployments, your CI/continuous integration, and anyone else who runs
> npm install in your package source to get the exact same dependency
> tree that you were developing on. Additionally, the diffs from these
> changes are human-readable and will inform you of any changes npm has
> made to your node_modules, so you can notice if any transitive
> dependencies were updated, hoisted, etc.

And in regards to the [difference between `npm ci` vs `npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci):

> - The project must have an existing package-lock.json or    npm-shrinkwrap.json.
> - If dependencies in the package lock do not match    those in package.json, `npm ci` will exit with an error, instead of    updating
>   the package lock.
> - `npm ci` can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.
> - If a `node_modules` is already present, it will be automatically removed before `npm ci` begins its install.
> - It will never write to `package.json` or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen.

Comment: I disagree, though I use npm install, not npm ci. With npm install, having package-lock.json on the repo causes issues in deployment.
see my answer on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206782/do-i-commit-the-package-lock-json-file-created-by-npm-5/54102769#54102769

Comment: @MagicLAMP You rather should use `npm ci` instead of `npm install` on your build server. Then your problem would go away.

Comment: Thanks @k0pernikus. I will try this in the week and comment again.

Comment: "npm ci" gives an error, where npm does not understand "ci" as a command. Is this shorthand for something. I tried 'c' on its own, and that did not work. I tried 'i' on its own and I think it just did an install

Comment: @MagicLAMP Check your npm version. `npm ci` is available since npm@5.7, current version is `npm@6.11`. You may update your npm via `npm install -g npm`.

Comment: @MagicLAMP And `ci` is not a shorthand, is it its own command with distinct behavior, namely: it nukes node_modules, installs all dependencies from the package-lock.json, without ever mutating it. Read the linked page for further details: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci

Comment: Fwiw the `.gitignore` on the [_webpack_ Github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/.gitignore) does include `package-lock.json`...

Comment: @JSStuball webpack uses yarn instead of npm. It has a yarn.lock (equivalent to package-lock.json) in its repository. See also: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/6930#issuecomment-377987981

Comment: @k0pernikus finally got npm ci working on my ansible deploy, and committed package-lock to the repository. This allows my front end developer to deploy things. Thanks.

Comment: don't use "npm ci" locally. It wastes network bandwidth..in my case it downloads chromium (150MB) every time

Comment: @Jundl `npm ci` should still use the cache inside  `~/.npm`. It only nukes the `node_modules`, but it should not always download everything. Is there anything special about your setup?

Comment: hm, I develop a node module and in the using typescript project "npm install" is periodically executed. Chromium is a dependency of the module under development

Comment: @Jundl Could you please open a new question in the form of "Why does npm ci not use cache for chromium dependency?" and reference minimal, complete and verifyable example of a package.json of yours? I would have a look then. You could link your question here.

Comment: I think that **dependency tree** is the key concept around `package.json` I'd advice to bold it in the quote you made above.

Comment: Awesome. This is the answer that I've been looking for. Thanks for your explanation !!!

Comment: This is very useful information that's not repeated enough around the web, so thank you. That being said, I would like to ask what is it, that I should do in case of conflicts during merge when it comes to `package-lock.json`? Because this happens from time to time and manually resolving the conflicts cannot be the way, right?

Comment: @Lurco Look at [merge driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-merge-driver)