# How do I disable the use of "npm install" in favour of "npm ci", but keep the ability to do "npm install <package_name>"?

Tags: npm

I would like to use `npm ci` instead of `npm install` for creating a reproducible environment each time a project is setup. Full details of the reasons for this approach can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48524475/1526396).

But since `npm install` is ubiquitous it may sometimes be used by mistake. Therefore I want to disable to use of `npm install` on a project.

I still want to be able to use `npm install <package_name>` to install individual packages, but disable the use of `npm install` when installing the entire project.

How can that be done?

I have already attempted using this:

```JSON
"scripts": {
  "install": "npm ci",
}
```

But it creates an infinite install loop, with the installation running again and again.