# How to only install production dependencies and then some, but without any development dependencies?

Tags: dockerfile, npm-install

Given the following Dockerfile and package.json, how do I get my image to only have what is defined as production dependencies in the package.json and the one additional dependency defined in the RUN --no-save layer, but not any of the development dependencies?

```
FROM node:16.14.2-alpine3.15
WORKDIR /opt/asd
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install --production
RUN npm install --no-save typescript
```

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "4.17.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ramda": "0.28.0"
  }
}
```

Running `docker build .` produces an image that has `node_modules` containing not only the deps I wanted but also the development dependencies. What do I need to change in the Dockerfile to avoid this?

Comment: you also should set NODE_ENV=production
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268259/how-do-you-prevent-install-of-devdependencies-npm-modules-for-node-js-package

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash conditionals syntax, but you also need to define $NODE_ENV as environment variable:

```
RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "production" ]; \
    then npm install --only=production; \
    else npm install; \
    fi
```