# npm production install still installing dev dependencies

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I'm trying to perform a Docker node/ts project. I don't want dev dependencies, for obvious reasons.

When I run `npm --production install` or `npm install --omit-dev` or `npm --production install --omit-dev`, and/or set `NODE_ENV=production` in the Dockerfile, npm is still trying to install prettier which is in my dev deps.

I have tried all options I could think of; `docker system prune`, running the docker build with `--no-cache`, and even changing the base image in the Dockerfile to "trick" docker into using no cache. Believe me, docker is not caching anything.

What could be happening here? I'm totally at a loss and using `--verbose` in the `npm install` doesn't add anything useful.

The answers [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268259/how-do-you-prevent-install-of-devdependencies-npm-modules-for-node-js-package) don't work, including the `--no-optional` flag.

The Dockerfile (no `.dockerignore` used):

```
FROM node:16

ENV NODE_ENV=production

# -- Setup --
RUN mkdir -p /app/
WORKDIR /app/

# -- Install --
RUN npm update
ADD package.json /app/
RUN npm install --omit-dev --verbose

# -- Copy in source --
COPY .env /app/
COPY src /app/src

## -- Start app --
CMD ["node", "./src/my_app.js"]
```

---

p.s. I know I could use something other than npm, but I would prefer to stick with the default option, if I can.

---

p.p.s Can work around this issue by simply removing the `devDependencies` section from my package.json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you prevent install of "devDependencies" NPM modules for Node.js (package.json)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268259/how-do-you-prevent-install-of-devdependencies-npm-modules-for-node-js-package)

Comment: Try Max's comment, and `NODE_ENV=production npm install` or `prod` instead of `production`.

Comment: If this is in a Docker context, can you [edit] the question to include the Dockerfile?  I've seen several multi-stage Dockerfiles go by that don't effectively manage the `node_modules` tree.  It's also worth double-checking that you have a `.dockerignore` file that omits the host's `node_modules` directory from the build context.

Comment: Thanks @Anuga, updated post to reflect that I tried this.

Comment: @goldfishalpha Can you share your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Also add: the dep/devDep/optionalDep part och the package.json (if you can). Pretty sure, omit is run like this: `--omit dev --omit optional` etc. Also provide the parts you can, of the output of `RUN npm install --omit-dev --verbose`. Setting the env of node should be enough for npm to not install the deps.